# Display php errors on osx

Tags: php, macos

I'm trying to get PHP to display errors with syntax etc, during development in OSX.

I have edited my php.ini as follows;

```
display_errors = On
error_reporting = E_ALL
```

However, I still can't get the errors to display. I'm just stuck with a blank page. This happens even with the simplest of pages;

```
<?php

echo "ook"

?>
```

This should throw an error.

I would be grateful if anyone has any ideas on how to resolve this? I have definitely edited the correct `php.ini`, because a `phpinfo` file tells me so.

Comment: that doesn't throw an error http://codepad.org/9XJYtZab

Comment: shouldn't this tell me that the semicolon is missing though?

Comment: copy paste the echo below the first echo without semicolon

Comment: There might be something wrong with your PHP or Apache install. Just try a generic MAMP package (http://www.mamp.info/en/index.html). It should work.

Comment: Thanks Richard. Looks like I may have to. I was trying to get away from installing any additional PHP/Apache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured out what the problem was. My phpinfo file was telling me that I was using php.ini so of course I had been editing that. What I have discovered was that there was also a php.ini.default file in the same folder. I have deleted this file and now errors are showing. :)

Answer (score 2):

I would also like to state that the PHP end-tag (`?>`) is considered to be an explicit semi-colon (`;`)...

The following script is valid:

```
<?php
echo "Hello";
echo "There"
?>
```

While the following is not:

```
<?php
echo "Hello";
echo "There"
```

Comment: So, if I entered the second piece of code into  page, should I see an error? As I just get a blank page. :(

Comment: @Neil: Second piece of code should of displayed an error. Did you restart Apache after modifying the `php.ini` file?

Comment: did u install the php and apache or are you using the default osx?

Comment: Sadly it just displayed a blank screen. Very confusing.

Comment: @Neil: Did you remember to restart Apache after modifying the `php.ini`?

Comment: @kjy112 I'm using the default OSX, but enabled PHP5 (as that was disabled by default). I also then setup some virtual hosting in the apache conf.

Comment: @Andrew Yep, I use sudo apachectl restart in Terminal.

Comment: Seems like nothing i change is making any difference :S

Answer (score 1):

If the syntax of the script is not valid, you might get a white screen of death instead of an error.  When you're testing error reporting, try a different error like dividing by zero.

Your php.ini line should read `error_reporting = E_ALL`, by the way.  `display_errors` should equal 0 or 1.

Edit: Oops!  Corrected factual error.

Comment: display_errors should be either On or Off, according to php possible values

Comment: Actually, starting PHP 5.2.4, the value can either be `Off` (`0`), `On` (`1`), or `stderr`. http://php.net/errorfunc.configuration

Answer (score 1):

I had a quite stupid problem which maybe someone else could also run into. In my php.ini I wrote accidentally:

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & E_STRICT
```

instead of:

```
error_reporting = E_ALL | E_STRICT
```

Which was filtering all the error messages. Took me a couple of minutes to find that stupid mistake. Hope I can save someone else's time ;).

Answer (score -1):

There is no requirement for semi-colon(;) for last line in PHP, it not an error, like following code has no error due to missing semi-colon:

```
<?php echo 'test' ?>
```

Or

```
<?=$x ?>
```

Or

```
<?php 

echo "test code"
?>
```

Or

```
<?php 

echo "Test Code"
```

Answer (score -1):

I was encountering the same problem, although I found the solution:

There were two php.ini files for me.

One in my home-brew folder which I found with the following command:

```
~ % php --ini
```

And the other in my XAMPP folder under the etc directory.

The latter had to be edited at the display_errors property
from Off->On